# Is there an easy way to create individual snippets in spring-restdocs?

Tags: spring-restdocs

I just dived into spring-restdocs and i really like the way how to document my API. Now I would like to extend the generated examples by python. Means I want snippets like the curl ones just for python.

this is what I found out so far:

I will have to create my own template like default-curl-request.snippet. Is it right that is followed by extending my own implementation by org.springframework.restdocs.snippet.TemplatedSnippet?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a template to generate the snippet then what you have described is the right approach to take.

Note that you don't have to use a template. You could opt to implement the `Snippet` interface directly and you're then free to generate a snippet using any means you like. [Here's a snippet implementation from a third-party extensions](https://github.com/ePages-de/restdocs-wiremock/blob/8e7f783b2915ce64a20e98d6b4133e0ff38db8d0/wiremock/src/main/java/com/epages/restdocs/WireMockJsonSnippet.java) that takes this approach.